# Select default dropdown from Api Service call angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to set the default value of my dropdown from the objects obtained from the service call to the first element to the array object array. I have followed various answers here the have options like use compare with but the default value set looks off on the dropdown plus when you select the dropdown that hardcoded default value does not disappear but move to the outside top of the drop down. This is now my code back to its initial state. The dropdown works correctly but has a blank value initially and I would like it to rather have the first object based on the name element of the array

TypeScript

```
  this.brokerageService.getBrokerages().subscribe(brokerage => {
             this.brokerageList = brokerage.filter( e => e.name !==  '');
              });.......
        
               selectedBrokerageChanged(event: any) {
               this.selectedBrokerage = event.value;
              }
```

HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="mat-form-field">
     <mat-select  name="brokerage" id="brokerage"
       (selectionChange)="selectedBrokerageChanged($event)">
   <mat-option *ngFor="let brokerage of brokerageList " 
     [value]="brokerage" >
    {{brokerage.name}}
   </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You litteraly have an example in the documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#getting-and-setting-the-select-value. The first element of an array is obtained by doing `yourArray[0]`.

Comment: I had tried both 
           [value]="brokerage[0].name"   throws an error  and
           [value]="brokerage[0]"  
  the drop down still  appear initaly empty with no set default value

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks like you are trying to set the first value for all the options, which is not possible. You must have unique object in the `value` of your mat-option.

`value` is the value that the mat-select will return when  an event is triggered like `selectionChange`.

Here is an [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cjv2yt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-value-binding-example.ts) about how you can do it easily and here is the code :

ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: "select-value-binding-example",
  templateUrl: "select-value-binding-example.html"
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample implements OnInit {
  selected = null;
  users$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    // this.http.get(...) should obviously go in a service, it's just shorter to show you this way
    this.users$ = this._http
      .get("https://randomuser.me/api?page=1&results=5&seed=abc")
      .pipe(
        map((data: any) => data.results),
        tap(data => (this.selected = data[0])),
      );
  }
}
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)" [value]="user">{{user.email}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>You selected: {{selected}}</p>
```

I used a little of rxjs to filter my data and set the selected value after the api call is made.

As you may know, the `async` pipe you can see in the html part do the subscribe to the API call. the `pie, map, tap` are rxjs functionality that allow you to do things with the result.